# Access Database Controlbox not displaying

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having some trouble with a database in Access. One of the forms is too big for the monitor and spills over off the edge of the screen. Now, this wouldn't be an issue if I could just set the form to full screen using the Minimize/maximise buttons.

However, no matter what I try (Changing from Tabbed/Overlay, ensuring the Controlbox is on, Min Max buttons on, Modal on) the Min Max buttons still do not appear. They do appear after going in and out of design mode, but that's not something I can ask the end user to do. I'm wondering if some VBA code would help but I can't find anything that will work, is there anything you fine people suggest?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To see the MIn/Max buttons, you must set the `Pop Up` property to true. This opens the form in its own window containing the control box.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunerly the PopUp property is already set to true, the form opens on its own but still doesn't display the control box :(

Comment: What is a 'predatabase'? Is this behavior replicated on a new form?

Comment: Him @june7 sorry about that, it was a typo. Long day.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question! E.g. you're missing own effort on research of vba code that may help. Search for "ms access vba form maximize"